# Visual Studio Blame/Annotation to same view

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, blame, git-blame

While using Eclipse and IntelliJ for Java development I got used to seeing the annotation lines in edit mode right next to the changes I'm working on. Well, apparently Visual Studio always opens the annotations to a separate uneditable window.

So the question is: is it possible (eg. with a plugin) to show the annotations (git in this case) in the editing view similarly as Eclipse and IntelliJ allow.

Comment: what do you mean by editable? It's in the history, you cannot change it.

Comment: I don't mean that the history should be editable, just that I would see the annotations (for those lines that are unchanged in the working copy) in the editing view instead of a separate view.

Comment: Don't think this is available for VS.  There's a plugin that does this for VS Code though called Git Lens: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#current-line-blame

Comment: Thanks for the tip @PhilipPittle. I do also use Visual Studio Code, so that's useful. It would be nice to get a similar thing for VS too though, as that's what I use for frontend development.

Comment: Haven't used this tool, but it might have some support for git diff: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HippoCampSoftwareLtd.CodeLineage#overview

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as asking for Inline Git Blame, similar to the GitLens extension on Visual Studio Code.

In Visual Studio 2022, this extension does the job: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jotting89.GitLineCodeLens&ssr=false#review-details